# Add FontAwesome icons to Glyphicon SVG

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, font-awesome, glyphicons

I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and there are these 2 icons in FontAwesome which I need in Glyphicon:

```
fa fa-long-arrow-up
fa fa-long-arrow-down
```

Been trying several methods from StackOverFlow like icomoon but I cant understand as I dont have enough experience in CSS/font things. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not simply including Font Awesome and calling up the very icons you want to use?

Comment: Yeah, I have been using Glyphicons everywhere in my site from start and they have icons which looks better then Font Awesome but not all matches.

Comment: Okay... but these two libraries don't conflict in any way. There is nothing stopping you from including *both*.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following cdn into your header:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Alternatively, you can use these bootstrap glyphicons:

```
glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up     //For the Up Arrow.


glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down    //for the Down Arrow.
```

Comment: These will load more files, the webpages size would increase as well.

Comment: How so? it is cdn after all, you are not downloading any files, just referencing the files' address hosted on the internet servers.